# Vue component get props by context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I am new in the VUE world, I start creating an app to render a list of TODO's, I pass the todo by props to the todo component, I was looking for another way to pass props to child component like react that you can create a context to share that data.

Todo.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-bind:key="todo.id" v-for="todo in todos">
      <TodoItem v-bind:todo="todo" v-on:del-todo="$emit('del-todo', todo.id)" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TodoItem from './TodoItem.vue';

export default {
  name: "Todos",
  components: {
    TodoItem
  },
  props: ["todos"]
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

TodoItem.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is-complete':todo.completed}">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="markComplete" v-bind:checked="todo.completed">
      {{todo.title}}
      <button @click="$emit('del-todo', todo.id)" class="del">x</button>
      </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TodoItem",
  props: ["todo"],
  methods: {
    markComplete() {
      this.todo.completed = !this.todo.completed;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  .todo-item {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px #ccc dotted;
  }

  .is-complete {
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }

  .del {
    background: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 9px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: not sure a) how vue is inelegant, and b) how react is more elegant!

Comment: Sorry, i am looking for another way to provide values to a child components in Vue, is not if it is elegant or not, i thing in react context there are in vue any feature like this? @JaromandaX

Comment: perhaps vuex - but I can't see a problem with how you're doing it. Is there some issue you are having?

Comment: No the code works fine, i only want to know another way to share data between components in vue, i am looking now vuex to see if it can do this.

Comment: as @JaromandaX said, vuex or maybe [nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context/). Or store it in cookies or localstorage if you're crazy enought ^^

Comment: How would you use `context` in react to give the `TodoItem` the specific todo item that it should display?

Answer (score 1):

As you're asking ways to share data between components in VueJS, you can find the answers by googling "state management in VueJs". I can sum up here, please comment here if there's a thing I'm missing:

- Passing data by props as you're already doing, data passed directly from parent to child.
- As the data want to pass around not that direct, you can use the technique called "lift the state up".
- Or by using a Vue specific technique called `eventBus`.
- The most standard way to "state management" in Vue would obviously be using VueX.
- Or another state management libraries like Redux, etc.
- Or event higher level, a framework built on top of Vue like Nuxt.
- After reading a comment above, I see a (pretty crazy :) way here is to use `localStorage/cookies`

Comment: How about mixins for shared functionality? if we are already on the topic of a shared context.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for nice suggesting. But I don't know if mixin should be included here because all I mentioned seems to only be state management techniques, mean passing data around instead of shared functionality as you mentioned. And another reason is I don't know if the new composition API would be better and totally overlap/ replace mixin or not (I'm still learning), so I'll take it as a consideration for more detailed answer about the Vue world if it gets more attention and I know more about Vue as well. Thank you anw.