# how to update the props in vue when the grandchild file has send the succeed PUT request

Tags: vue.js

i have three vue.js file. where the parent file (`parent.vue`) contains data of `profile:[]`

the data of profile is send to child file (`child.vue`) using `props` methods.

the `child.vue` also has it's own child file (`grandchild.vue`) that has been pass with the `profile` data by using props.

grandchildren will send a put request to API to change some data in profile.

my question is. how can i make sure the props will update on every change made in the profile data.

information : (`parent.vue` = main file, `child.vue` = drawer(from ant design), `grandchild` = popover)

i need the `child.vue` to update the profile data after the grandchild succeed send a put request to the API.

is there any way or reference link so i could make the props update after a put request from `grandchild.vue` i have tried watch method but the problem is the user need to close the drawer (child.vue) first and re open the drawer to update the props. is there any way the props update without closing the drawer?

example of code :

parent.vue :

```
// structure
<child.vue
  :profile="profile"
/>
```

child.vue & grandchild.vue :

```
//script
props : [profile],
```

profile can be used as {{`profile.subsdata`}} in html or `this.profile.subsdata` javascript

Comment: Appropriate use of `:key` binding would probably help but it's very difficult to provide advice when you haven't shown any code

Answer (score 1):

Use an emit. Tell the parent component to update via another GET request or just pass the data back directly.

Child Method:

```
notifyParent () {
     this.$emit('updateProfile')
}
```

Parent Template:

```
<ChildComponent v-on:updateProfile="someMethod"/>
```

Parent Method:

```
someMethod () {
     //GET request or whatever
}
```

More details here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: This would have been an excellent question, but you forgot v-on event listeners inside DOM templates will be automatically transformed to lowercase (due to HTML’s case-insensitivity), so v-on:myEvent would become v-on:myevent – making myEvent impossible to listen to. So capital letters are wrong

Comment: @FrancoMaldonado This is only the case if you don't use SFC. Behind the scenes they use kebab-case, but you can absolutely use camelCase in the template. It isn't even anti-pattern in this case, just a matter of taste. If you generate components globally, then you must use kebab-case.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword here is [`eventBus`](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860), you need an eventBus to $emit an event changing the data in the `parent` component from the `grandchild` component. If you only need to change up the data 1 layer instead of 2 in this case, you only need custom event + $emit, without the eventBus. But as it's greater than 2 layers, you need `eventBus`, or even [more relegent ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59239667/9787887) to do state management.

Comment: I'd suggest that the if $emit is commonly used or there are any cases of prop-drilling, you're better of implementing Vuex for state management. If it is a very small app, using the eventBus may not be bad, but it's going to be much more in line with best practices to use a store.